# How do I delete my typo3cms database?

Tags: typo3

Help is requested to delete a database I have created in TYPO3 setup.

I have installed XAMPP in Ubuntu 16.04 and configured it correctly and it runs. Now I was in the process of configuring TYPO3 in XAMPP using this very good [guide](http://www.webdevblog.org/install-typo3-cms-on-xampp-on-ubuntu/).

After creating the "typo3cms" database, the next stage asked for a user name and password. I think I was supposed to put in my Ubuntu username and password, but erroneously I put in a new username and password and got the error of not being able to connect to my database.

I tried to go back to the previous stage of creating a database, which I can't because it already exists. But then I cannot go forward anymore. I have no idea where the database resides so that I can delete it and recreate it. I have tried uninstalling typo3 and reinstalling it. I have tried to google the problem without success.

Short of purging xampp completely and starting from scratch, is there a way I can delete the typo3cms database I have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are so early in the install process that you can start over (by removing all files and doing the install from the beginning).

Alternatively you should be able to remove `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` and make sure that `FIRST_INSTALL` exists in document root (this is an empty file used to indicate that TYPO3 is doing the first install, it gets removed after - and you can use `touch FIRST_INSTALL` in terminal to create the file). Or if you prefer a completely manual approach, manually edit the `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` file to correct or remove the database credentials and then resume the install.

Comment: Thanks @Due for your time. I think I will go with your first suggestion to remove all files and start all over. I do not have typo3conf on my system because I had uninstalled typo3 and reinstalled without beginning to configure.